# How to execute 1 method of all implementations in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have some classes below. Obviously, if I invoke "printMessage" in CustomAtm class, it will execute the method in PrinterFile because I declared it by @Qualifier. But I wonder Is there any way to execute both "printMessage" method in PrinterConsole and PrinterFile when I invoke it and I don't declare @Qualifier ?

Printer interface

```
public interface Printer {
    void printMessage(String message);
}
```

PrinterConsole class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("printerConsole")
public class PrinterConsole implements Printer {
    @Override
    public void printMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

PrinterFile class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("printerFile")
public class PrinterFile implements Printer {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrinterFile.class);

    @Override
    public void printMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

CustomAtm class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("customAtm")
public class CustomAtm {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("printerFile")
    Printer printer;

    public void printCurrentMoney() {
        printer.printMessage("Current ATM money is... ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say Spring is not a magic. Simply, it will create a specific instance of your class and inject. If you want to directly invoke 1 time for 2 different instance class, it can not. You need an apdater or something two wrap them.

Comment: Ok I also think so. This is my trainer's question. Maybe it is what he meant. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up all instances that are registered as bean and implement the Printer interface:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("customAtm")
public class CustomAtm {
    @Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void printCurrentMoney() {
        Map<String, Printer> printers = context.getBeansOfType(Printer.class);
        for(Printer printer: printers.values()){
            printer.printMessage("Current ATM money is... ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, we get all the beans of Printer and use for loop. I accept your answer until there is a better solution :D thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Method 1
Inject list of printer

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private List<Printer> printers;


public void printAll() {
    for (Printer printer : printers) {
        printer.print();
    }
}
```

Method 2
you can define another class that combine the 2 beans

```
@Component("printerAdapter")
public class PrinterAdapter implements Printer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("printerFile")
    Printer printerFile;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("printerConsole")
    Printer printerConsole;

    @Override
    public void printMessage(String message) {
        printerConsole.printMessage();
        printerFile.printMessage();
    }
}
```

And in your client class inject the new printer class and use it

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("printerAdapter")
Printer printer;
```

Comment: It's not what he wanted to ask

Comment: yes, I know that method 2 but I mean I don't use @Qualifier and call method from only 1 Printer like this  `Printer printer;
        //code ....
        printer.printMessage("message");
        //code ....` :D Any way thanks for your rely

Comment: what about method 1? you can even make this class implements printer and use use its printMessage implementation calls printAll

Comment: Yes, I would consider using it. Thanks. sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote :v